# ModelSim freezes when it executes [gets stdin]

Tags: tcl, modelsim

I have a TCL stript steering my ModelSim simulation. I would like to be able to break the simulation, ask user for some input and continue. `vsim_break` is not exactly what I want. I've tried  `set user_input [gets stdin]`, but the simulator freezes immediately. Are there other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `gets stdin`, Tcl (normally) waits until it receives a line from standard input. If you want to keep a GUI (or other background-processing system) going but still wait for a line, you need a slightly different approach.

```
proc getStdinLine {} {
    set ::user_input [gets stdin]
}
fileevent stdin readable getStdinLine
vwait ::user_input
# Unregister the callback
fileevent stdin readable {}
```

***BEWARE!*** This code can have problems with reentrancy; if your script manages to get back to the same point while it is waiting, it can very easily get itself in a real mess. This is because `vwait` keeps a record of what is being waited for on the C stack; this remains true even in Tcl 8.6 (though that has coroutines which you can use to create a workaround, if ModelSim is cooperative enough).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works better now. Is there a possibility to request user input from the ModelSim console instead of stdin? Changing to the unix console when user input is needed is kind of ugly.

Comment: @Andy A good question, but not one I know the answer to (as I'm not a ModelSim user, and work in a different field). I do know that ModelSim uses Tk, so you ought to be able to pop up a dialog box (with a `toplevel` and a `label` and an `entry`) but that's too much to go into in a comment.